# Random walk in rethinking::ulam

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, random-walk, rethinking-r-package

I have been trying to implement a [random walk](https://mattsosna.com/R-3-For-loops/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20steps%20to,the%20parameters%20of%20the%20walk.) in `rethinking::ulam`. I'd be interested in how to do this in general after reading discussions such as [this](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/random-walk-prior/3086) and [this](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/random-walk-or-autoregressive-prior-in-brms/28411/10) on how to build random walks in Stan and its other R interfaces such as `brms`.

Here is a MRE for a specific case trying to model the decay parameter *k* of the exponential decay function *f*(*x*) = *a* * *e*^(-*k* * *x*) as a function of *x* using random walk:

```
# generate data
set.seed(10)
x <- 1:250
r <- rnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(x^-1.5))
y <- 2 * exp(-0.04 * x) + r

require(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x = x, y = y)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal()

# prepare data for ulam
l <- as.list(df)
l$N <- length(l$x)

# run model
require(rethinking)
rw.mod <- ulam(
  alist(
    y ~ dnorm(mean = mu, sd = sigma),
    mu <- a * exp(-k * x),
    k <- 0.04,
    for (i in 2:N) {
      k[i] <- k[i - 1] + r
    },
    r ~ dnorm(mean = 0, sd = tau),
    a ~ dlnorm(meanlog = log(2), sdlog = 0.5),
    c(sigma, tau) ~ dexp(rate = 1)
  ), data = l, chains = 8, cores = parallel::detectCores(), iter = 1e4
)
```

This yields the following error: `Error in get_dist_template(the_dist[1]) : No template for distribution ':'`

I also tried specifying the vector `2:N` in the `for` loop as `seq(from = 2, to = N, by = 1)`, in which case I get the same error: `Error in get_dist_template(the_dist[1]) : No template for distribution 'seq'`

Any solutions or pointers would be greatly appreciated! If there is no solution in `rethinking::ulam`, I'd be grateful to understand how to do this in Stan, since there seems to be no vignette online and I did not understand the linked discussions on discourse.mc-stan.org.

#### Update

Random walk is not currently possible in `rethinking::ulam` and a [feature request](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking/issues/423) has been added. I am currently figuring out how to use Stan instead, which you can follow [here](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/random-walk-in-rstan/34308/4). Solutions in Stan are still greatly appreciated.